# Tensorflow get the default device name

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow 1.14 I'm trying to use `tf.data.experimental.prefetch_to_device(device=...)` to prefetch my data to the GPU. But I'm not always training on a GPU, I often times train on a CPU (especially during development).

Is there a way to get the current default device in use? Tensorflow either picks the CPU (when I set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1`) otherwise it'll pick the GPU, the default usually works.

So far I can only find a way to list visible devices with `sess.list_devices()`, but there must be a way to query the current default device so I don't have to manually change it in `prefetch_to_device` every time, right?

Comment: so do you want to get the current device being used by tensorflow while running a session? Or do you want to know which device will be used once you start your session?

Comment: Ideally I want to know which device would be used once a session is started, though I suppose either would provide a suitable answer. I want to know how to fill out `device` in `prefetch_to_device` without adding it as a parameter I feed to python. Tensorflow does a good job of picking the default before session is created. All OPs get loaded to the `gpu:0` if a GPU is available, otherwise they go on the CPU. I just want the same with `prefetch_to_device`.

Comment: ok, I assume that you want an API way of doing it and currently there seems to be none. You can create a custom function that will iterate over available devices and try with them one by one but I understood that is not what you want. I have made a separate post to this end, check it out

Comment: after you `import tensorflow as tf`, try running `tf.test.gpu_device_name()`. If you get `'/device:GPU:0'` where `0` is the index, then GPU is in use, else you get `''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API way of doing what you said currently. The closest

> `device = 'gpu:0' if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else 'cpu'`

is what you have already said.

The reasons I think so is that the allocation is done at a low level: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cf4dbb45ffb4d6ea0dc9c2ecfb514e874092cd16/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/colocation_graph.cc

Maybe you can also try with [`soft placement`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I've found so far is to use `tf.test.is_gpu_available`:

```
device = 'gpu:0' if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else 'cpu'
```